ASUS laptop boot issue, complete black screen
I changed from Legacy BIOS to UEFI and I saved the changes, and after that my ASUS laptop went into complete black screen, so I switched off my computer. (I thought the update was complete)
After around 10 hours I booted it again and the power indicator is on, the fan was able to be turned on, and it just lasted there without anymore reactions. HDD started for a split second while booting and stopped. No more reactions whatsoever.
I tried performing hard reset, reseating ram and took out the battery but nothing seemed to work. Can I still recover my laptop?
My computer specs:
CPU: Intel Pentium P6200, 2.13Ghz
HDD: 320 GB
RAM: 2GB
Not sure about the graphic card
ASUS X42J series

Why did you change it? Based on the system describe your operating system was installed with CSM enabled. I am honestly shocked your system even utiltized a UEFi firmware based on the age of the device.

The UEFI option was there.

I didn't say I doubted you that the option was there, I am trying to understand, why you enabled it since you likely were not running an operator system installed in UEFI mode. It's very likely the laptop firmware is bricked.

Therefore, this cannot be recovered by any conventional means?

I used to activate UEFI and it succeeded, but for the second time it failed, I also did activate some effects graphic effects when booting, does that affect the computer? @Ramhound

What exactly did you activate?

I probably changed the boot logo to animation instead of static


Restore BIOS/UEFI to defaults. 2. Restore drive image you made before starting these changes. 3. If no image. boot from USB (e.g., Macrrium Rescue Environment or Hiren's Biit CD PE), save data, then reinstall Windows.


This question is similar to: Deleted BIOS boot options on laptop can't boot from anything. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It seems like it booted normally yesterday, and I checked the BIOS, it reverted my changes, so the problem is resolved, if tho I am not sure how.
